# How to use .ENV variables when publishing npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, environment-variables, dotenv

How do I inject my environment variable into the final build that gets published to npm?

I'm using the dotenv package and that works great locally. However when I do `npm publish`, the env variable is gone since it just runs the file in the main property of the package.json.

Some relevant fields from package json:

```
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "typings": "./lib/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "lib",
    ".env"
  ],
  "scripts": {
     "start" : "tsc && node -r dotenv/config ./lib/index.js"
  },
  "bin" : {
      "run-app" : "./lib/index.js"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    }
```

.gitignore:

```
# OSX
.DS_Store

node_modules
notes.MD

lib
.env
```

I tried to inject my env variable by passing it to my start script and also call the .config() method on dotenv inside the code. Either way the env variable ends up undefined when running my package using `npx`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .env mostly not for production. But you can use it, of course. Can you share `gitignore`, `dependencies` in `package.json` and `bin` in `package.json`?

Comment: Well I'm using a token secret in the code so I don't know how else to do it. Updated post :)

Comment: Here you are ignoring the .env in your `gitignore`. Just remove the last line. Also use it inside `lib/index.js` as `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: It seems like the .gitignore file matters, I'm not sure exactly why. Now my secret will be visible in the git repo though and as you said it's also visible in the npm package itself. Any good advice for dealing with secrets when publishing npm packages?

Comment: I have no solution to the secrets issue, but a bit of clarification: npm supports a `.npmignore` file to list the files that should not be published to the registry. If that file does not exist, it falls back to `.gitignore` under the assumption that if you don't want a file in your git repository, you don't want it in your package either. You can read more about it [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).

Comment: Ok, I was just slightly confused because i thought the files property overruled both of those. You should post it as an answer by the way so I can accept it ;)

Comment: @jones it's not an answer though, since your question is how to deal with (secret) environment variables. I was just responding to the "It seems like the .gitignore file matters, I'm not sure exactly why." comment.